# Groovy. Call a member of a class which does not exist

Tags: groovy

How can I make IDE to recognise calls of nonexistent members of the Groovy class  as error or at least how can I find all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Groovy 2 you can annotate the class as `@groovy.transform.TypeChecked`, though obviously this will prevent you from using any dynamic features such as `MarkupBuilder` that rely on being able to call "non-existent" method names. [This article by Guillaume Laforge](http://www.infoq.com/articles/new-groovy-20) has the full details.

Depending on your IDE it may already give you some visual feedback. For example, I use Eclipse with the GGTS plugins, and this highlights calls it can't resolve statically using a solid underline. This includes any method calls on untyped (`def`) variables, so it's less useful than `@TypeChecked` which does a certain amount of type inference.